# C# DirectorySecurity SetOwner on subcontainers and objects

Tags: c#, .net, user-permissions, directory-security

I am trying to change ownership of a windows folder and everything inside it.  Basially I am trying to check the box that would be there if you did this manually in windows that says "Replace owner on subcontainers and objects".  This will need to work over a network share path.  I am able to get 1 folder deep but then it just stops there.  This does not include the base folder changing either.

```
 foreach (string directory in Directory.GetDirectories(dirPath))
            {
                var di = new DirectoryInfo(directory);
                IdentityReference user = new NTAccount(Login.authUserName.ToString());
                DirectorySecurity dSecurity = di.GetAccessControl();
                dSecurity.SetOwner(user);
                di.SetAccessControl(dSecurity);
            }
```

Comment: Looks like you just need to call your method  recursively for every subdirectory you encounter

Comment: @HasaniH I was hoping for a cleaner way, but it seems like that might be the only way to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `Directory.GetDirectories` with `SearchOption.AllDirectories` in order to recurse.

But it seems easier to just get the `DirectoryInfo di` objects directly using `DirectoryInfo.GetDirectories`, which has the same and more recursive options.

```cs
IdentityReference user = new NTAccount(Login.authUserName.ToString());

var root = new DirectoryInfo(dirPath);
foreach (var di in root.GetDirectories("*", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly).Prepend(root))
{
    var dSecurity = di.GetAccessControl();
    dSecurity.SetOwner(user);
    di.SetAccessControl(dSecurity);
}
```

Comment: Thanks.  I ended up manually doing it, but this actually was what i was looking for i think.